# Ошибка JSON - JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)

Tags: python, json

Нужно считать JSON файл. Выдается ошибка `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Так выглядит сам код:

```
def getJSON(self):
    json_file = 'http://192.168.31.194:8000/static/files/09IPL.json'
    res_json = requests.get(json_file).text
    
    return res_json
    
def jsonParse(self):
    res_json = self.getJSON()
    data = json.loads(res_json)
    
    return res_json
```

JSON файл вида:

```
{"Название": [
{
  "Физлицо": "ФИО",
  "Подразделение": "подразделение",
  "Должность": "должность"
}]}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Буквально ошибка говорит о том, что в строке встретился UTF-8 BOM маркер (byte order mark - [маркер порядка байт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)), и нужно было декодировать (пришедшие с сервера) байты с помощью кодировки utf-8-sig (utf-8 с учетом BOM).

В данном случае нужно принудительно указать кодировку в ответе сервера, потом уже доставать текст:

```
result = requests.get(json_file)
result.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
res_json = result.text
```

Также можно сразу декодировать json без отдельного `json.loads`:

```
result = requests.get(json_file)
result.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
res_json = result.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Если сайт действительно отдаёт `json`, то не нужно его преобразовывать вручную, берите сразу готовый `json`, тем более в хедерах и т.д. наверняка была указана кодировка, а вы, взяв от сайта только `.text` всю эту информацию отрезали:

```py
res_json = requests.get(json_file).json()
                                  ^^^^^^^
```

Хотя бывает, что это тоже не работает, и тогда кодировку нужно угадывать.

Comment: Возвращает `<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>`

Comment: @Arteil, `()` справа от `json` кто забыл добавить?

Comment: @insolor `requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)] `

Comment: @Arteil значит свой комментарий под вопросом оформлю как ответ